# SQL - How to update a field in a record to summed value from two tables

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm having a problem getting a table to update and am hoping that maybe someone here can help me out.  I'm just learning SQL, so I'm not sure of the best way to do certain processes.  I have a value in one of my tables that somehow got out of whack.  Now, I need to update it using the original value minus the sum of values in a different table.

Table 1 is ORDER_LINES.

```
ORDER_NO QTY_ON_ORD ORIG_ORD_QTY
0900476          10          100
```

Table 2 is INVOICED_LINES.

```
INV_NO SHIP_QTY ORIG_ORD_NO
000441       20     0900476
000441       25     0900476
000441       15     0900476
000441       10     0900476
```

Value of ORDER_LINES.QTY_ON_ORD should be:

```
ORDER_LINES.QTY_ON_ORD =
ORDER_LINES.ORIG_ORD_QTY - SUM(INVOICED_LINES.SHIP_QTY) 
WHERE INVOICED_LINES.ORIG_ORD_NO = ORDER_LINES.ORDER_NO
```

So, the value of ORDER_LINES.QTY_ON_ORD is not correct.  The values in these are constantly changing, so I'd like to have a SQL command that I can run to update these on the fly.  I've tried many things such as:

```
UPDATE "ORDER_LINES"
SET QTY_ON_ORD = SELECT (
  (SELECT SUM(ORIG_ORD_QTY) FROM "ORDER_LINES" WHERE ORDER_NO = '0900476') - 
  (SELECT SUM(SHIP_QTY) FROM "INVOICED_LINES" WHERE ORIG_ORD_NO = '0900476')
)
WHERE ORDER_NO = '0900476';
```

But that doesn't work.  The Selects by themselves print out the correct qty in my query, but I can't seem to use that qty in my update.

We're running Pervasive SQL if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can update using `merge` or `update from join`

Comment: How does your query not work?